# convert EnumerableRowCollection<string> to List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to return this collection in a function:

```
List<string> codes = ( from q in Data.AsEnumerable() select q.Field<string>("START") );
return codes;
```

This throws error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

What's the best way to return such a collection?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since [EnumerableRowCollection<TRow>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb907979.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<T>` you can just add a `ToList()` at the end:

```
using System.Linq;

List<string> bankCodes = ( from q in QueueData.AsEnumerable() select q.Field<string>("START") ).ToList();
```

or alternatively

```
List<string> bankCodes =  QueueData.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<string>("START"))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: add .ToList() throws this exception:

Comment: 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Meidi - You need to add a `using System.Linq;` directive to the top of your file.

Comment: @Lee that was my only problem that missing using System.Linq upvote for you

Comment: I was missing system.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `.ToList()` to covert it into list so try something like this.

```
List<string> bankCodes = ( from q in QueueData.AsEnumerable() select q.Field<string>("START")).ToList();
```